# How to make special format of date and time in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, react-native

I need to extract date and time separately from the following format.
The total date and time format is in `props.info.positionState.timeEnter`:

```
2017-11-06 16:55:10
```

Now, I need to put `2017-11-06` in `timeEnter_date` and also I need to put `16:55` in the `timeEnter_time`.

My code is like below:

```
this.state = {
          timeEnter_date : (props.info.positionState.timeEnter),
          timeEnter_time : (props.info.positionState.timeEnter),
        };
```

I should mentioned that, I used `.format("hh:mm"),` but, it did't work for me. Can you help me how to manage it?

Comment: have a look at moment.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best date-time handling lib in javascript is [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).

```
this.state = {
  timeEnter_date: moment(props.info.positionState.timeEnter).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
  timeEnter_time: moment(props.info.positionState.timeEnter).format('HH:mm:ss')
};
```

Here is [.format method docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,the solution is good and I have already voted it up but, for this solution I need to install moment. Is there any alternative way that doesn't need any installation?

Comment: @Queen why don’t you want to use moment? If you’re working frequently with time, it could be your best friend! :)

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla javascript is solusion:

```
this.state = {
  timeEnter_date: new Date(props.info.positionState.timeEnter).toISOString().slice(0, 10),
  timeEnter_time: new Date(props.info.positionState.timeEnter).toISOString().slice(11, 16)
};
```